# DataTable Linq with two join statements in C#

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

My code:

```
var Result = from TempRow in ArrAbsDiff
             where TempRow.Strike == StrikeOfMinAbsDiff
             select TempRow.PutMidPrice;
```

I know that the above code return just one value of type decimal (maybe double). However, Result is of type `Enumerable` and I could not easily write `Result + 2`. I need to convert it property. I can do it through the following code:

```
var Result = (from TempRow in ArrAbsDiff
             where TempRow.Strike == StrikeOfMinAbsDiff
             select TempRow.PutMidPrice).Min();
```

Is there more efficient way to accomplish it?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know that the above code return just one value of type decimal

Then use `First` method instaed of `Min`.

Answer (score 2):

At compile time, it's unknown whether the query you have returns 1 record or more than 1 record.  So, it assumes a list of them.

I don't know if there is a performance difference between them, I typically use .Single() to get the single record.  It's more clear that I want a single record and not, for example, the minimum one.

Answer (score 1):

Try using FirstOrDefault()" this selects the first result returned (as you know only one value will be returned). if a value is not returned the Result will be null, catch this in an if statement like below:

```
var Result = (from TempRow in ArrAbsDiff
             where TempRow.Strike == StrikeOfMinAbsDiff
             select TempRow.PutMidPrice).FirstOrDefault();

if (Result == null)
    return; // or error message
```

this will also keep the type of value returned
(typed this of the top of my head, may need slight changes!)